# Sending PushBots notifications directly from the server

Tags: pushbots

I am new to Android Development

I have an app where people sell stuff and others buy it..

I want to notify buyers when someone put a new item for sale.

for that I used PushBots notifications, but the only way I can send notifications to users are by writing them on PushBots.com and send it there

Is there any way I can send notifications automatically whenever items are available for sale?

Thanks

Comment: GCM, you can try google cloud messaging services

Comment: you mean i dont need PushBots?

Comment: search for it. you will understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pushbots REST API detailed [here](https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/rest-api-getting-started).

I used their [PHP Library](https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/php).

Answer (score 0):

I used Pushbots REST API here https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/nodejs

And later used the nodemon module for nodejs to watch if a file changes and send the push the notification.